# Js/Jquery: how to filter on distance data-distance?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have items such as:

```
<div class="user" data-distance="400">user2</div>
<div class="user" data-distance="500">user2</div>
<div class="user" data-distance="600">user3</div
<div class="user" data-distance="700">user4</div>
```

How can I display div.user whose distance<600 ? (hide those whose distance>=600)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`, `.end()`, `.show()`, `.hide()`

```js
$("[data-distance]")
.filter(function(i, el) {
  return +$(el).data("distance") < 600
})
.show()
.end()
.filter(function(i, el) {
  return +$(el).data("distance") >= 600
}).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user" data-distance="400">user2</div>
<div class="user" data-distance="500">user2</div>
<div class="user" data-distance="600">user3</div>
<div class="user" data-distance="700">user4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `filter` method and `data` to get distance. This will return filtered elements that you can use to replace `html` of parent element or `body` in this case.

```js
$('body').html($(".user").filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('distance') < 600
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user" data-distance="400">user1</div>
<div class="user" data-distance="500">user2</div>
<div class="user" data-distance="600">user3</div>
<div class="user" data-distance="700">user4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use [].forEach.call() to loop over all $('.user'):
[].forEach.call($('.user'), function (div) {
    // you need to make wrap it (it's just a bare HTMLElement)
    div = $('div');
    // get the distance
    var distance = div.data('distance');
    // ignore if distance is absent
    if (distance != null) {
        // If data-distance is defined in the HTML source,
        // then you can use the selector ".user[data-distance]".
        // If you defined it with element.data('distance', 42),
        // then the selector would be unreliable.
        if (+distance < 600) {
            // hide:
            distance.css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            // show:
            distance.css('display', 'inherit');
        }
    }
});
```